# Convenient way to print the search path for packages in R project

Tags: r, path, package

we are several users who use the same R script but from different machines. R is installed on a server and packages are installed locally and on the server.

If I run the code then everything works fine. If my collaborators run the code then some packages are loaded with a different version number.

What is the most conveniant way to e.g. print the search path of every session/user to the GUI?

Comment: `sessionInfo()` or `.libPaths()` ?

Comment: .libPaths() should work - thank you !

Comment: @hadley if you make it an answer, then I will accept - thanks

Comment: @Richard you can answer and accept your own answer. Hadley provides good answers just in comments quite often. He did with my questions as well :-)

Comment: Meanwhile, to *solve* the problem,  maybe you want a (non-R) script which mirrors the server's packages over to the users' machines.